# does using pre-built docker images saves space on container registry?

Tags: docker

Suppose I built a docker image `xyz` (let's say it's size is `a`), now I am using this docker image in other docker images, let's say I built two new images which have `FROM xyz` command in their dockerfile and their respective size is `b` and `c`. All these three images are stored in a container registry like AWS ECR. My question is, does using pre-built images reduce your overall size occupied in container registry. What I mean by that is, will the total size be `a + b + c` or `a + (a+b) + (a+c)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of a Docker image is given by the sum of all its layers.
So if you build image `b` on top of image `a`, then the final size of the image `b` will be that of `a` and `b` (given by the size of its layers). This same reasoning of course applies to `a` and `c` as well.

So the total size for the three images on ECR will be:

- `a`
- `a` + `b`
- `a` + `c`

To optimize the size of your images you can leverage [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#use-multi-stage-builds).